# Failed to load external entity SOAP SSL

Tags: php, ssl, soap, wsdl

I using PEM certifacte to autheticate WSDL requests.

```
$cert = '/etc/.../cert.pem';
$client = new SoapClient('https://somesservice.com/service.asmx?WSDL', 
 array( "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
 "local_cert" => $cert));
```

I getting **failed to load external entity** error.
If i try get wsdl by curl

```
 curl --key /etc/.../cert.key --cert /etc/.../cert.pem "https://somesservice.com/service.asmx?WSDL"
```

it works fine

Edit:
Or maybe my PEM certifacte must have a private key section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy content of KEY file to my PEM file certificate so correct answer is: "YES, PEM file have to contains private key section"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send the content of your certificate such as:

```
$cert = '/etc/.../cert.pem';
$client = new SoapClient('https://somesservice.com/service.asmx?WSDL',
    array(
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        "local_cert" => file_get_contents($cert),
    )
);
```